# how can i get only text in flutter using rest api

Tags: flutter, dart, rest

Hey all i'm getting data from  rest api everything is working fine but i want only text data. anyone pls help me.

```
{
   "description": {
      "blocks": [
         {
            "key": "1h2pe",
            "text": "Delicious, loquats are very low in calories; provide just 47 cal per 100 g, however, rich in insoluble dietary fiber, pectin. Pectin retains moisture in the colon and thus functions as bulk laxative and by this way, it helps to protect the colon mucous membrane by decreasing exposure time to toxic substances as well as binding to cancer causing chemicals in the colon.Pectin has also been shown to reduce blood cholesterol levels by decreasing its re-absorption in the colon by binding bile acids resulting in its excretion from the body.Loquat fruit is an excellent source of vitamin-A (provides about 1528 IU per 100g), and phenolic flvonoid antioxidants such as chlorogenic acid, neo-chlorogenic acid, hydroxybenzoic acid, feruloylquinic acid, protocatechuic acid, epicatechin, coumaric acids and ferulic acid. Ripen fruits have more chlorogenic acid concentrations.Vitamin A maintains integrity of mucus membranes and skin. Lab studies have shown that consumption of natural fruits rich in vitamin-A and flavonoids helps to protect from lung and oral cavity cancers.Fresh fruit is very rich in potassium and some B-complex vitamins such as folates, vitamin B-6 and niacin and contain small amounts of vitamin-C. Potassium is an important component of cell and body fluids, helps controlling heart rate and blood pressure.It is also a good source of iron, copper, calcium, manganese, and other minerals. Manganese is used by the body as a co-factor for the antioxidant enzyme, superoxide dismutase. Copper is required in the production of red blood cells. Iron is required for as a cofactor in cellular oxidation as well for red blood cell formation.",
            "type": "unstyled",
            "depth": 0,
            "inlineStyleRanges": [],
            "entityRanges": [],
            "data": {}
         }
      ],
      "entityMap": {}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the 'Text" data by...

```
void main() {
  
   var mydata = {
    "description": {
      "blocks": [
        {
          "key": "1h2pe",
          "text":
              "Delicious, loquats are very low in calories; provide just 47 cal per 100 g, however, rich in insoluble dietary fiber, pectin. Pectin retains moisture in the colon and thus functions as bulk laxative and by this way, it helps to protect the colon mucous membrane by decreasing exposure time to toxic substances as well as binding to cancer causing chemicals in the colon.Pectin has also been shown to reduce blood cholesterol levels by decreasing its re-absorption in the colon by binding bile acids resulting in its excretion from the body.Loquat fruit is an excellent source of vitamin-A (provides about 1528 IU per 100g), and phenolic flvonoid antioxidants such as chlorogenic acid, neo-chlorogenic acid, hydroxybenzoic acid, feruloylquinic acid, protocatechuic acid, epicatechin, coumaric acids and ferulic acid. Ripen fruits have more chlorogenic acid concentrations.Vitamin A maintains integrity of mucus membranes and skin. Lab studies have shown that consumption of natural fruits rich in vitamin-A and flavonoids helps to protect from lung and oral cavity cancers.Fresh fruit is very rich in potassium and some B-complex vitamins such as folates, vitamin B-6 and niacin and contain small amounts of vitamin-C. Potassium is an important component of cell and body fluids, helps controlling heart rate and blood pressure.It is also a good source of iron, copper, calcium, manganese, and other minerals. Manganese is used by the body as a co-factor for the antioxidant enzyme, superoxide dismutase. Copper is required in the production of red blood cells. Iron is required for as a cofactor in cellular oxidation as well for red blood cell formation.",
          "type": "unstyled",
          "depth": 0,
          "inlineStyleRanges": [],
          "entityRanges": [],
          "data": {}
        }
      ],
      "entityMap": {}
    }
  };
  
List  firstList = mydata.values.toList();
List secondList = firstList[0].values.toList();

  
  
  print("${secondList[0][0]["text"]}");
}
```

Comment: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.

Comment: which specific element is saying that?

Comment: i'm using rest api with future builder in flutter.. how can i get text from description

Comment: I've updated my answer. FYI: This may not be a good way to do it, but it gets the job done.

Comment: ListTile(
                  title: Text("Benefits:",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                   List  firstList = mydata.values.toList();
                   List secondList = firstList[0].values.toList();
                   print("${secondList[0][0]["text"]}");

          
                ),

Comment: how can i integrate this under list tile

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Adapter class for whatever JSON you're trying to access in Dart.
In Java, they are called POJO classes.
Declare all the variables i.e., 'keys' as variables of type 'value' in a class, and use getters to access individual fields.

Comment: i'hv created all these im using flutter and for rest api using future builder. everyting is working fine but i want to get description and in description i want to get text under the description. so tell me any solution of this problem

Comment: I guess this might help you to generate proper POJO classes. 
Kindly refer this link, just copy paste your json response, give a name for your adapter class, and then press generate.

https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/